# File.Copy corruption over network

Tags: c#, file, networking, copy

I am using the following code to copy files from a network location to a local drive.

```
try
{
    File.Copy(remotePath, localPath, true);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    File.SetAttributes(localPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
    File.Copy(remotePath, localPath, true);
}
```

I catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException` in case the local file exists and is marked read-only. Otherwise I let other exceptions be thrown.

This generally works 99.9% of the time. In rare cases, the files are not copied properly.

- They show the correct size at the destination, but the contents of the files are all `0`s.
- No exceptions are thrown.
- The source files are not corrupt.
- The files are copied from a Windows Server 2003 machine to Windows 7 machines.

Is there anything that can be done to catch this problem except for verifying file hashes after copy?

Comment: I do not know, but try copy "manually" with a Stream writer (but I understand it is difficult to test one-tenth percent of the cases...).

Comment: We started having this issue after changing data centers. The servers in both data centers are Windows 2008 R2, however the new servers are virtual where the old servers were physical. Did you ever find a cause?

Comment: @Chad_K To be honest I can't really remember. I checked the code base and it doesn't look like I ended up doing anything differently so either the problem went away or I deemed the failure rate acceptable. The server in question was not virtual.